# Namespaces in vendor files (CakePHP2.x and PHP5.4.3)

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces, cakephp-2.2

I want to use a css parser that uses namespaces. I put the files in vendors and app imported it. but the script itself does not seem to find its classes

At the top of my class I import the file:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Sabberworm', array('file' => 'Sabberworm/CSS/Parser.php'));
```

which is in /root/vendors/Sabberworm/CSS/ (all files are in this namespace)

Inside my class method I create a new instance:

```
public function parse($content) {
    $oParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($content);
    ...
}
```

So far so good. But if I now want to call `$oCss = $oParser->parse();` it fatal errors:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Sabberworm\CSS\CSSList\Document'"
```

it fails then because it requires the other files (which should be loaded using namespaces). the root vendors folder is in the include path and the foreign script seems to set the namespace to "namespace Sabberworm\CSS;". what am I missing? I am kinda new to namespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to bootstrap

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    foreach(App::path('Vendor') as $base) {
        $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            return include $path;
        }
    }
});
```

Or just this inside the function:

```
$path = APP . 'Vendor' . DS . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
if (file_exists($path)) {
    include $path;
}
```

Comment: I like the first one. It worked right away (I put it into the lib class which uses the vendor stuff). thanks a lot! now i can continue working on the AssetSprite stuff.

Comment: I referenced it in http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/08/06/namespaces-in-vendor-files-and-cake2-x/

Comment: How about in cakephp 1.2 and 1.3

Comment: One note: you should "return" after the include. Someone mentioned that on the referred blog article.